# Defining my own datatypes within my own metamodel using EMF Ecore

Tags: eclipse, emf, mda, ecore

I was wondering how can I define my own datatypes within a metamodel created using EMF Ecore ?

The goal is to have a class that may contain many attribute. Each attribute has one Datatype.

The problem I am facing now is when I want to set the attribute datatype [in a model which is conforme to my metamodel ] in the Property View (Eclipse EMF), I get an empty list.

I want something similar to when adding an EAttribute , you get the choice between different Etype (EString, EBoolean,...).

I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add EDataType instances on the same level as EClasses, and they can refer to any kind of Java object. However, be careful that only very simple serialization is available for these objects.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but I couldn't understand what you meant by "adding to the same level as EClasses".

Comment: I tried to use EDataType instances, but I couldn't attach them to my other Eclass instance. What is the problem ?

Comment: I meant, EDataType instances are similar type definitions to EClasses. The difference between them is in case of EDataTypes you can only refer a Java class, while in case of EClasses you define its attributes in the metamodel. To refer these EDataTypes, you have to define attributes in your EClasses that have this new type.